# How to hide symbols of iPhone app binary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I checked several IPAs downloaded from the App Store by running `strings'.
None of them shows meaningful symbol.

But the binary I built in the release 
mode shows all the symbol names in the strings output.

Comment: I believe Apple stores .ipa files in the special way and they had the decryption problem not so far ago, not sure that's true though.

Comment: If you get your app to distro from the app store it will also act like that.

Answer (score 1):

In your Project Build Settings, set *Strip Debug Symbols During Copy* to `YES` for *Release*. That's the default.

If that doesn't work, try toggling these build settings:

- Symbols Hidden by Default
- Strip Linked Product